# How do I access RabbitMQ natively without IP address using amqplib?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

Where I work we have a cloudfoundry server that provides RabbitMQ as a service. When I configure this service and try to connect using amqplib via (localhost, 127.0.0.1, etc) it doesn't connect. When I look at the Java project, it never configures an IP and seems to connect natively through a driver or something (using Spring).

How would I connect using amqplib without an IP? Should I use another node lib instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a connection without setting the hostname but then the hostname is set as "**localhost**" as described in the [documentation](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#connect).

If your RabbitMQ is on a remote server you must provide

- a remote IP address
- port (if it is different from the default 5672)
- username and password of not default user as mentioned [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#loopback-users)

You may not be able to make a connection due to closed port on the remote server is closed, [check it via telnet](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1514049471-Check-whether-a-remote-server-port-is-open-on-Linux)